# Get the most top-level item of a QTreeWidgetItem

Tags: python, pyqt, qtreewidget, qtreewidgetitem

I would like to find the most top-level parent item of a `QTreeWidgetItem`, no matter how many levels deep it is in the tree.

Problem with using `item.parent()` is that it could return another `QTreeWidgetItem` if the item is several levels deep in the tree, so I would end up having to do `item.parent().parent().parent()...etc` for example.

Comment: Have you heard of the while() loop?

Comment: Aren't you just looking for [`QTreeWidget::invisibleRootItem`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtreewidget.html#invisibleRootItem)?

Comment: Or... are you trying to get the child of the invisible root item that's also an ancestor of the `QTreeWidgetItem` of interest?  If so you just need to implement a simple iterative or recursive algorithm that searches towards the root and stops at the appropriate point.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't explain my question well. But `while` loop is indeed the solution, this will keep searching until it finds the top-level item of the item:

```
while item.parent():
    item = item.parent()
```